# How to store a particular value from database and save into cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select folderlocation from fsfilestorage 
                                 where id='"+sessionid+"'", con);
SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader1.Read();
string folder = string.Empty;
folder = reader1.GetString(0);
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` to get single value from db and add it to `Response.Cookies`

```
var folder=cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("folder");
myCookie["FolderPath"] = folder;
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```